# Estendendo método da Classe Pai em C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma classe esfera :

```
class CEsfera{ 
    protected: 
       double centro[3]; 
       double raio;

    public: CEsfera();

    CEsfera(double x, double y, double z, double r); 

    mostra() { 
          for (int i=0; i<3; i++) 
                cout << centro[i] << “, “; cout << raio;
    } 
};
```

com um raio definido e com uma funcao que mostra os atributos xyz e o raio.

preciso de criar uma classe derivada que inclui-a o atributo peso e (re)defina o método mostra() para que apresente no ecrã todos os atributos, incluindo os herdados da classe pai.

e criar método que devolva o valor da densidade de uma bola (=peso/volume, volume=4/3 π r^3) que não deve escrever nada no ecrã.

c) Defina um método que devolva o valor da densidade de uma bola (=peso/volume, volume=4/3 π r^3). Este método não deve escrever nada no ecrã.

**Declaração da Classe Cesfera**

```
class Cesfera{
    protected:
      double centro[3];
      double raio;
        double vol;

    public:
    Cesfera();//const defeito
    Cesfera(double x, double y, double z, double r);// const enum
    Cesfera (const Cesfera&);
    void mostra(double x, double y, double z, double r);
    void calcvol();
    double volume(){return (vol);}
};
```

**Definição da Classe Cesfera**

```
void Cesfera::calcvol(){
   vol = pi*raio*raio*raio*(4.0/3.0);
}

Cesfera::Cesfera(double x, double y, double z, double r){
   centro[0]=x;
   centro[1]=y;
   centro[2]=z;
   raio=r;
}

void Cesfera::mostra(double x, double y, double z, double r){
     for (int i=0; i<3; i++) cout << centro[i] << ", ";
     cout << raio;
}
```

**Declaração da classe Cbola (estende Cesfera)**

```
class Cbola: public Cesfera {
  int peso;

  public:
    Cbola():Cesfera(x,y,z,r){}

    // Cbola(double x, double y, double z, double r, int p);
    void calculadens();
    void mostra0(double a, double b, double c, double d, int p);
};
```

**Definição da classe Cbola**

```
void Cbola::calculadens(){
    dens = (peso/vol);
}

void Cbola::mostra0(double a, double b, double c, double d, int p){
     for (int i=0; i<4; i++) 
           cout << centro[i] << ", ";
     cout << raio<<endl;
     cout<<p<<endl;
}
```

**Main**

```
int main(){

    Cesfera esfera1(1,4,5,6);// constructor enumeracao
    esfera1.mostra(1,4,5,6);//chama para escrever

    Cbola bola1(1,4,5,6,8);// tenho o erro aqui no matching construct

    bola1.mostra0(1,4,5,6,8);
    esfera1.calcvol();// calc volume

    return 0;
}
```

A minha duvida é como é que consigo que a função `mostra0` na classe derivada use os parâmetros da classe mãe e acrescente o novo parâmetro?

Supostamente com o public na classe derivada os parâmetros da classe base não ficam disponíveis para a função `mostra0` usar?

Answer (score 1):

Orientação a Objeto em C++ é bem diferente de Java, você precisar tornar o método `mostrar0` da classe Pai também como virtual para ser possível defini-la na classe Filho. O public não significa que você pode substituir tudo. Tente utilizar na classe Pai

```
virtual void mostra0(double x, double y, double z, double r) = 0;
```

E na classe Filho

```
void mostra0(double x, double y, double z, double r)
```

com a mesma assinatura de  parâmetros.

Além disso, uma vez que o método é virtual, não é possível definir o seu código na Classe pai, somente nas classes que a estende, utilizando os mesmos parâmetros.

Comment: Não precisa deixar abstrato para fazer o poliformismo funcionar. Só o `virtual` é o suficiente. Quando você se refere às diferenças na orientação e objetos Java vs C++, é como se no Java todos os métodos fossem `virtual`.

Comment: ja corrigi os pontos acima indicados no entanto obtenho erro:  public:
    Cbola():Cesfera(x,y,z,r){}// erro uso em undeclared identifier x, y, z, supostamente o meu constructor por enumeraçao da Cesfera nao deveria tratar destes parametros?

Comment: É que você não declarou  x,y e z, pois o Construtor do filho não definiu os parâmetros. o certo deveria ser Cbola(x,y,z,r):Cesfera(x,y,z,r)

Comment: O :Cesfera(x,y,z,r) é simplesmente uma chamada ao construtor do pai. antes de executar o construtor do filho. Assim como o super(x,y,z,r) do JAVA

Comment: Ah ok  basicamente é o elo de ligação entre o constructor pai para o constructor do filho.  Após alterar tenho erro  c++ requires a type specifier for all declarations.  Ele não deveria passar o tipo do parâmetro?? Neste caso de tipo double?

Comment: Cbola(double x,double y,double z,double r):Cesfera(x,y,z,r)